# Would 'the type of people who work' or 'the type of people who works' be the one?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct?

A: "the type of people who work a lot"

or

B: "the type of people who works a lot"?

I think it is B, but my girlfriend who is a native speaker told me the correct answer is A.

Comment: @Lambie I look for unanswered questions. But you have answered this one. You even say it is the answer. Why don't you post the answer as such? It would save time for those of us who try to give answers to new questions.

Answer (score 1):

The type of people who work a lot.

**People in English has a plural meaning, does not take an s and is, therefore, never used with a third person ending on the verb**.

People like the zoo. People go  fishing on Sunday. People are nice when they want to be.

Comment: Is it not worth comparing "people who work a lot" and "the type . . . which works a lot" ?

Comment: But in "the type of person who works a lot", would you say the meaning is the same?